# Неправильно работает, после * ,/ пишет "Выбрана неверная операция!"

Tags: python

там после * ,/ не должно писать Выбрана неверная операция!
а от с + и - всё в порядке.

## Калькулятор #1

```
#
from colorama import init
from colorama  import  Fore ,  Back ,  Style 


init()

print( Fore.GREEN )

what = input( "Що робим? (+, -, /, *): " )

a = float ( input("Ведить перше число: ") )
b = float ( input("Ведить друге число: ") )

if what == "/":
    c = a / b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))
if what == "*":
    c = a * b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))
if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))
elif what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("Результат: " + str(c))
else: 
    print("Выбрана неверная операция!")
input()
```

Comment: Потому что про elif забыли.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в вашем варианте кода если выбрать `/` или `*` - выполнится одно из первых двух условий. Но в таком случае нет ничего, ограничивающего остальные условия... они всё равно будут проверяться, окажутся ложными и сработает хвост else. А чтобы не было такой ошибки, все операции вместе должны быть в одной "цепочке". Чтобы одновременно могло сработать только одно:

print кстати тоже не обязательно добавлять под каждым условием. Всё равно в конце надо будет что-то выводить.

```
what = input( "Операция? (+, -, /, *) >>> " )

a = float ( input("Первое число >>> ") )
b = float ( input("Второе число >>> ") )
c = ""

if what == "/":
    c = a / b
elif what == "*":
    c = a * b
elif what == "+":
    c = a + b
elif what == "-":
    c = a - b

print( c if str( c ) else "Выбрана неверная операция!" )
input()
```

Можно еще так)

```
oper = {
    "+": lambda a, b : a + b,
    "-": lambda a, b : a - b,
    "*": lambda a, b : a * b,
    "/": lambda a, b : a / b,
}

a = float( input("Первое число >>> ") )
b = float( input("Второе число >>> ") )
what = input( "Операция? (+, -, /, *) >>> " )

print( oper[what](a,b) if what in oper else "Выбрана неверная операция!" )
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам не надо запрашивать числа, если операция неверна.

```
from colorama import init
from colorama  import  Fore ,  Back ,  Style 

init()
print( Fore.GREEN )

what = input( "Що робим? (+, -, /, *): " )
if what!="+" and what!="-" and what!="/" and what!="*":
    print("Выбрана неверная операция!")
else:   
    a = float ( input("Ведить перше число: ") )
    b = float ( input("Ведить друге число: ") )

    if   what == "/": c = a / b
    elif what == "*": c = a * b
    elif what == "+": c = a + b
    elif what == "-": c = a - b

    print("Результат: " + str(c))

input()
```

Comment: `if what not in ["+", "-", "/", "*"]:`?